# How to select records in ax based on month or year only?

Tags: axapta, x++

I am new to AX development. I was looking for to_char equivalent in AX so that i can select records based on month and year only. I want to select all the records for one particular month only irrespective of the date.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a date range instead.

```
date d  = today();
date d1 = startMth(d);
date d2 = endMth(d);
while select ledgerTrans 
    where ledgerTrans.TrandDate >= d1 &&
          ledgerTrasn.TransDate <= d2
{
    ...
}
```